# Python3 curses segfault on stdscr.refresh()

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, curses, macos-ventura

Here is a very small program that demonstrates the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import curses
import sys
import time

def main():
    try:
        stdscr = curses.initscr()
        stdscr.clear()
        stdscr.addstr(0,0, "This is the prompt")
        stdscr.refresh()
        time.sleep(3)
    finally:
        curses.endwin()
    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

If I change `python3` to `python`, it works perfectly. With python3, I get a segmentation fault in the call to `stdscr.refresh()`.

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/109617

Comment: could be - but about halfway through the bug report, it morphed from Apple's problem into further problems created by the python developers.

Comment: Interesting. Bug report says it's specific XCode v15, but I don't even have XCode installed on my system. Not sure where curses came from on my Mac. Worth noting: this isn't crashing on a Linux system, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: seems to be a bug in Apple's bundled Python. I went straight to python.org and downloaded their latest version and the problem seems to have gone away. Thanks for your help everybody.

Leaving this as not officially solved for a while, in case someone comes up with a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using curses.wrapper instead of manually initializing and ending curses to see if it resolves the segmentation fault.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import curses
import sys
import time

def main(stdscr):
    stdscr.clear()
    stdscr.addstr(0, 0, "This is the prompt")
    stdscr.refresh()
    time.sleep(3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    curses.wrapper(main)
```

Comment: No joy. This is clearly https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/109617. Installing Python directly from python.org fixed the problem. Apple is just shipping a broken curses.